# Global AS3 File - FDT

Tags: actionscript-3, fdt

I'm trying create a global file in AS3 with FTD.
It's a file that is imported by this code

```
<fx:Script source="../../../framework/util/util.as"/>
```

and is acessible by all classes in project. 
Just like this without package or class.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
import mx.controls.Alert;
import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridColumn;
import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
import mx.core.UIComponent;
import mx.formatters.DateFormatter;
import mx.managers.ToolTipManager;
import mx.messaging.Channel;
import mx.messaging.events.ChannelEvent;
import mx.messaging.ChannelSet;
import mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel;
import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
import mx.rpc.remoting.mxml.RemoteObject;
import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;

import spark.components.TitleWindow;
import spark.events.TitleWindowBoundsEvent;

private var channelSet:ChannelSet = new ChannelSet();
private var customChannel:Channel;

public function showErrorImmediately(target:UIComponent):void
{
    // we have to callLater this to avoid other fields that send events
    // that reset the timers and prevent the errorTip ever showing up.
    target.callLater(showDeferred, [target]);
}
....
```

In FB this file works fine but when i migrate to FDT a lot of errors occurs.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What errors? Please provide more information.

Comment: Compile error, FDT requires me to use package and class. Just like this .Multiple annotations:

Unexpected Token . at line 3 column 10.
Unexpected Token . at line 4 column 10.
Unexpected Token . at line 4 column 19.
Unexpected Token import at line 4 column 1.
Unexpected Token ; at line 1 column 31.
Unexpected Token DataGridColumn at line 5 column 36.
Unexpected Token . at line 7 column 15.

Comment: I'm almost sure you cannot use `public` and `private` statements outside of a class.. And at least you must have a package! :)

Comment: but this is a characteristic  of FDT?

Answer (score 1):

FDT does not support the source attribute for MXML script tags:

```
<fx:Script source="../../../framework/util/util.as"/>
```

Your code in file *util.as* is valid if you consider it as contents of a script block.
I assume you put the file *util.as* in some package in your source folder.
In this case FDT assumes it is a normal compilation unit. A normal compilation unit 
has to start with a *package* and so FDT complains about that.

In general it is a bad practice to use the include statement or the source attribute and this is why FDT does not support that.

In your case I would consider defining your own abstract mxml component as base class of all your components containing the method and the fields.